# compare a list (int values) with 1 int

Tags: list

I need to compare the ID with the list.. But somehow it isn't working

```
<%@ page import="java.net.URLEncoder, java.util.ArrayList, java.util.HashMap" %>
<%
    int someID = 1500;
    int someList[] = new int[]{1296, 1297, 1298, 1299, 1500};
    for(int i = 0; i < someList.length; i++){
        if(someList[i] == someID){
%>
            <a href="blablabla.html">Option 1</a>
<%
        }else{
%>
            <a href="blablabla.html">Option 2</a>
<%
        }
    }
%>
```

Comment: What language/framework is this? Please use tags.

Comment: it's java used in jsp pages

but the other code on the page is working so there's only something wrong with this part..

Answer (score 1):

put a semi-colon after the first statement?

Comment: obviously that's not the problem, I just copied it wrong.. but thanks for noticing